# CMD all output to one log file

Tags: logging, command-line, cmd, output

So,

I have a single BAT file with some commands which I'd like to output to a single log.txt file.

Is there a way (at the beginning of a BAT file) to tell CMD that it should output all warning/errors/everything to a single log.txt and not to console? 
Or do I need to append "dir > log.txt 2>&1" on every command individually?

Tnx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try changing

```
@echo off
    batch commands
    ....
```

into

```
@echo off
    call :doCommands %* > file.txt 2>&1
    exit /b

:doCommands
    batch commands
    .....
```

Comment: Tnx MC ND. 
I used Your suggestion: 

call :doCommands %* >> %var%\log.txt 2>&1 
PAUSE 
Exit /B 
:doCommands
:: some commands 
GOTO :eof

Could You please tell me what's the difference between EXIT and EXIT /B?

Comment: in short: `exit /b` ends your script, `exit` ends your cmd-session.